# Easy SQL Server - VS.NET data migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ide

I have searched and searched (because I know the answer is out there), but can't seem to find it.

I only have VS.NET 2013 as my means to access a SQL Server for development (i.e. no SQL console, etc.)

I work in 2 locations - the office and home.

Occasionally, I want to get a snapshot of the entire DB at work to bring home so I have the current data set/structure at home.  Since this is not a currently deployed product yet, we have not yet completed the application code to handle this.

I have tried using the export data tier and created a `.dacpac` file. But I can't figure out how to consume that using the SQL Server object explorer in VS.net at home.

I know this is really easy to do, but can't figure out what I am missing. The key is to be able to do this entirely within VS.NET.

Thanks!

Comment: "The key is to be able to do this entirely within VS.NET." That's a shame as I do this regularly but using SQL Server Management Studio (I program in VS). Is SSMS definitely not an option?

Comment: Actually, it just dawned on me to see if they have an "Express" version that I can download - which they do - so will try that. (Hitting head, doohhh) - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this seems to be the only way to mark the question answered, I am doing so.

The suggestion by Stephen resolved the issue - that tool still doesn't make it easy to migrate a development related DB back and forth - but it's a good step and technically solves the problem.